# Parallel namespacing conflict

Tags: c#, unit-testing, namespaces

I have a unit test project that mirrors the directory and namespace structure of my application, except that the unit test project wraps everything in a `Test` namespace.  So a test for this class:

```
MyModule.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClass
```

would be defined in this class:

```
Test.MyModule.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClass
```

I'm running into problems in the unit test project when I try to create instances of objects defined in the regular (non-unit test) project if an identically-named class also exists in the unit test project.  Using the example above, if I create a variable of type `MyClass` in my unit test project using its fully qualified type name:

```
MyModule.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClass myobject = new ....
```

the compiler assumes I'm referring to the `MyClass` object defined within the `Test` namespace, and doesn't treat the type name as a fully qualified name.

The easy solution is to restructure my unit testing namespaces, but I'm curious if there's a way around this.  I need some way to "force" the compiler to treat the type name as fully qualified - a way to "break out" of the `Test` namespace.  Is there any way to do this?

If not, is there a better convention to clearly namespace my unit tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more searching, I came across the `global` keyword, which tells the compiler to assume the type name is fully qualified:

```
global::MyModule.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClass
```

[Here's the reference for the `global` keyword on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an alias for the namespace.
eg

```
using implementation = MyModule.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace;
```

then in the test

```
implementation::MyClass myClass = new...
```

Here's the docs about it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I usually have something that looks like this:

```
MyCompany.MyProduct.MyModuleTests.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClassTest
```

This usually makes it pretty clear to people and also plays well with TFS builds that will try to detect unit tests in all assemblies with "Test" in the name.

If you're really attached to your naming convention, you can use an alias for a namespace at the top of the test file:

```
using MyRealStuff = MyModule.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace;
```

And used in code:

```
MyRealStuff.MyClass myobject = new ...
```